# Unix Remove Duplicate uniq vs Sybase - ignore_dup_key

Tags: unix, sybase

I have a file with 20 Million records. It has 30% duplicate values.
We thought of implementing two approaches.

1. Writing shell script to remove the duplicates, the file will be uploaded in unix box.
2. creating a table in sybase with ignore_dup_key and the BCP the file as is into the table. so that the table will eliminate the duplicates.

I have read when the duplicate percentage increases the ignore_dup_key will impact the performance. 
How about the performance of Unix - uniq method? which one will be applicable for this?

Inputs are welcome!

Comment: I would go with option 2. Wouldn't want to re-invent the wheel. Since you are going to create index on the table, make sure you mention the batch size of the transaction with `-B`.

Answer (score 2):

Doing a BCP into a table with an ignore-dup-key unique index should be fastest, not in the last place because it is much easier and simpler to implement.

Here is why: ultimately, in either scenario you end up inserting a set of rows into the database table and building an index for those inserted rows. That amount of work is equal for both cases.
Now, the BCP method uses the existing index to identify and discard duplicate keys. This is handled quite efficiently inside ASE, as the row is discarded *before* being inserted. The number of duplicates does NOT affect this efficiency in case you only want to discard the duplicates (whoever said that was incorrectly informed).
If you'd do this duplicate-filtering outside ASE, you'd need to figure out a sorting method that discards records based on uniqueness of a part of the record (only they key). That's less trivial than it sounds and also requires system resources to perform the sort. Those resources are better spent on doing the sort (=index creation) inside ASE -- which you already had to do anyway for the rows being finally inserted.

Regardless, the BCP method is much more convenient than external sorting since it requires less work (less steps) from you. That's probably an even more important consideration.

For further reading, my book "Tips, Tricks & Recipes for Sybase ASE" has a few sections dedicated to ignore_dup_key.

Answer (score 1):

Without testing both approaches, you cannot say which is faster for sure. But using sybase approach will be faster more probably since databases are optimized  parallize your workload.